# Toxicity of vanadium in pottery

Tags: safety, transition-metals, toxicity

I mix and develop glaze recipes for midfire stoneware (fired to 1220°C). The colorants in pottery are mostly iron, copper, cobalt, tin, titanium, chrome, and a few other transition metals. Many of these materials are somewhat toxic in the raw form but safe in the finished work. These colors usually make up less than 3% of a glaze recipe.

Vanadium is a colorant that potters seem to fear without good reason. I find resources such as MSDS sheets to be very unhelpful on this subject.

The heart of my question is: in your humble-I-am-not-going-to-sue-you opinion, is vanadium (specifically tin-vanadium) safe enough? How about relative to cobalt?

Comment: See [this](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/10382561) abstract on Pubmed for information concerning the toxicity of vanadium and its salts. The net of it is don't inhale: "Most of the toxic effects of vanadium compounds result from local irritation of the eyes and upper respiratory tract rather than systemic toxicity."

Comment: I'd point out that there are two different toxicity problems, first to the potter and then to the user of the fired pottery.

Comment: Yes, vanadium is safe enough relative to cobalt.

Comment: Thank you.
Everything with mixing dry glazes is a respiratory hazard so that isn't a new worry.

Comment: I'd be more worried about what sort of toxic species might be released when the glazed items are fired. You'll breath all of that in.